# SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2005-express

Can anyone decipher this error message? Somebody gave me a SQL script and when I run it, I get this error:

[image: http://i890.photobucket.com/albums/ac103/mmh924/image001.png]

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the script?  It sounds like you might be having issues with quotes, but we'd have to see it.

Comment: I hope that you removed the password for purposes of the screen shot, and that you aren't really using sa/blank. On a local machine protected by other means it probably isn't a big deal, but it's not a very good practice.

Comment: It's a local machine.  I'm investigating now.  Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: For SQL Server 2005 and newer, you should stop using `osql` and instead use the new `sqlcmd` tool instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an instance of SQL Server Express, it is likely a named instance. So try adding `-S .\SQLEXPRESS` to the command.

Also see this blog post for common troubleshooting ideas: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might not have remote connections enabled on the SQL Server you are trying to run this script against.  Take a look at this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the Server name parameter specified in there.

```
`osql -U sa iP -i dbattach05.sql`
```

You might want this

```
`osql -S ServerOrInstanceNameGoesHere -U sa iP -i dbattach05.sql`
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do something like this if its an Express edition: http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/